# "How pacific do these errors have to be?"

Tags: meaning

I have just read this comic, and not quite sure what is the mistake in the last sentence "How pacific do these errors have to be?". Should it be peaceful instead of pacific? (English is my second 
language.)

[image]

Comment: If you had problems with that last error, I wonder if you cot all the others: **Frame 4**: Your (should be You're); allergys (should be allergies); affect (should be effect). **Frame 5**: their (should be there); its (should be it's). **My comment**: cot (should be caught). Just in case you mist one (I hope you don't have the same allergy).

Comment: Does that guy in the last frame need a comma after *God*?

Comment: Or ***pathetic*** even? That seems more in line with the rest of the dialog. ("I'm allergic to grammatical errors", frame-3, ...)

Comment: ‘If you want to impress small-minded educational snobs, then putting some time into the most intellectually trivial details of standard written English, the familiar grammatical and orthographic shibboleths, is a good investment.’ Geoffrey Pullum, Professor of General Linguistics, University of Edinburgh

Comment: @Kris, it might be more coherent with the story line, but given that all the other errors are very common, I suspect that `specific` is the right answer, as that mistake is far more common (in my experience).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ha!  It's supposed to be *[specific](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/specific)*.

> 2a : restricted to a particular individual, situation, relation, or
> effect
>
> Ex. *a disease specific to horses*

Comment: This is an all too common (and annoying) replacement of one word with another similar sounding one.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with what cornbread ninja has written. The whole set of sentences uttered in the bottom drawings is marred with errors. To be correct, they should read :

"***You're*** coughing up blood! I didn't know ***allergies*** could cause such a bad ***effect***!"
"Are ***there*** others like you? (It) Looks like ***it's*** getting worse."
"How ***specific*** do these errors have to be?"

So the term you pointed out comes at the end of a long series of mistakes, thus contributing to the comic effect of the whole.

---

While I was writing my post, there was someone more rapid than me who commentated upon the same. Sorry if mine then seems to be a double.

Comment: as always, your answers are better than the answers of native English speakers. +1

Comment: Paola, no need to say "sorry" for the double. Thanks for commenting on my speedy typing skills – you flatter me!

Comment: +1. Nice analysis of grammar. It is also possible the word is *pathetic* in place of *pacific*. The overall grammatical context in the cartoon does appear so.